# In the StarCraft II Galaxy Editor, how can I create a watchtower that provides vision of another area than itself?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

I want to create a watchtower that does not provide vision of itself when captured, but rather a completely random unrelated part on the other side of the map. Also, can a map still be a melee map with such a radical change to a watchtower?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested pseudo-code, so it probably won't work right-off-the-bat - (I used to use the BW map editor)

> Reveal map trigger
>
> ```
> Events
>     Unit - Any Unit Enters Within 2.0 Of Xel'Naga Tower (30, 100)
> Local Variables
> Conditions
> Actions
>     Visibility - Create a visibility revealer for player x within region
> ```

Sources:

- http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/4038704300#2
- http://www.sc2mapster.com/forums/development/triggers/38714-how-to-make-a-watchtower-that-provides-vision-of-another/#p3